# python pandas DataFrame cannot get the first column data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using Pandas to do data processing, and I encounter a problem, it cannot get the first column data, but can get other columns data, why? how can I solve this problem, could anyone help?

I just imported the data of the excel file, and wanted to get the Name data (first column)by

```
data['Name']
```

[image]

Errors are shown as below

```
KeyError          Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/test/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2392             try:
-> 2393                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2394             except KeyError:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/_libs/index.c:5239)()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/_libs/index.c:5085)()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/_libs/hashtable.c:20405)()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/_libs/hashtable.c:20359)()

KeyError: 'Name'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-67-47e6fa66308a> in <module>()
----> 1 school_names = processing['Name']

/Users/test/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2060             return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
   2061         else:
-> 2062             return self._getitem_column(key)
   2063 
   2064     def _getitem_column(self, key):

/Users/test/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _getitem_column(self, key)
   2067         # get column
   2068         if self.columns.is_unique:
-> 2069             return self._get_item_cache(key)
   2070 
   2071         # duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionality

/Users/test/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in _get_item_cache(self, item)
   1532         res = cache.get(item)
   1533         if res is None:
-> 1534             values = self._data.get(item)
   1535             res = self._box_item_values(item, values)
   1536             cache[item] = res

/Users/test/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in get(self, item, fastpath)
   3588 
   3589             if not isnull(item):
-> 3590                 loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
   3591             else:
   3592                 indexer = np.arange(len(self.items))[isnull(self.items)]

/Users/test/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2393                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2394             except KeyError:
-> 2395                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2396 
   2397         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/_libs/index.c:5239)()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/_libs/index.c:5085)()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/_libs/hashtable.c:20405)()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/_libs/hashtable.c:20359)()

KeyError: 'Name'
```

Comment: Post code as text not images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspect `processing.columns` and check whether `'Name'` is really in there. 
Pay extra attention to possible spaces.

Answer (score 0):

The last line should reference the dataframe named "data".

```
school_names = data['Name']
```